# Allocating array of struct pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, malloc

I couldn't find answer of the exact question, since the condition is a bit more specific:
How can i allocate array of struct pointers.

```
typedef struct COORDS
{
  int xp;
  int yp;
} coord;

coord** xy;
```

i want to allocate it like: `xy[500][460]` But it returns invalid memory error when accessing them.

Comment: For starters, `new` is a reserved word. Are you trying to allocate in heap or declare it in stack?

Comment: The compiller is old and its really old C.
new is not a reserved word in my case, but i will edit the example.

Comment: `new` is only a reserved word in C++

Comment: @Amarghosh `new` is reserved in c++ but not in c (which this question is tagged). That being said, it's still a very good idea to avoid use of c++ keywords in c.

Comment: To allocate such a large array statically it needs to either be global and/or static. Alternatively use malloc to allocate it dynamically.

Comment: @mah I think it's a good idea to use c++ keywords in C; it will alert someone who accidentally uses a C++ compiler on your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Static allocation:**

```
coord xy[500][460];
```

**Dynamic allocation:**

```
coord** xy = (coord**)malloc(sizeof(coord*)*500);
for (int i=0; i<500; i++)
    xy[i] = (coord*)malloc(sizeof(coord)*460);

// and at a later point in the execution of your program
for (int i=0; i<500; i++)
    free(xy[i]);
free(xy);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
coord** new = malloc (500 * sizeof (coord*));
int idx = 0;

for(; idx < 500; ++idx)
    new [idx] = malloc (460 * sizeof (coord));
```

Comment: Sorry to say. But it again gives the same error, using this code.
The access is: `xy[1][2].xp = 20;`

Comment: @Lively: Does your code compile without warnings?

Comment: It is pretty ancient built-in compiler from a game engine.
The coded posted by @barak manos ..work'd however.